# Geometry function from lat/long in Hasura not working

Tags: postgresql, hasura

I have a table with Locations, including the lat and long and geometry column. I want to calculate the nearest location from a user using the following query within Hasura:

```
query {
  near_locations(args: {distance: 30000, lat: 123.123, long: 12.22}) {
    city
  }
}
```

The function I use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.near_locations(distance integer, lat double precision, long double precision)
 RETURNS SETOF location
 LANGUAGE sql
 STABLE
AS $function$
SELECT * from location
 WHERE ST_DWithin(geolocation, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(long, lat), 4326), distance)
$function$
```

When I delete the lat and long variables in the function and add a static lat/long everything seems to work correctly...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like hasura has native support for PostGIG topology operators.

So the query I end up using is:

```
query nearby_users {
  location(where: {geolocation: {_st_d_within: {distance: 40000, from:  {
        type : "Point", 
        coordinates: [4.895168, 52.370216]
      }}}}) {
    id
    city
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @edwinN1337 thanks, this works but how do I get the distance between the coordinates in the query & results?